# for loop to generate "1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100"

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

how can I write a for loop to give this output? I was thinking a nested loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
```

but i don't know how to go from there?

thanks

Comment: I'll give you a clue, you only need one loop.

Comment: Can you see a pattern in these numbers? They are not just arbitrary numbers between 1 and 100.

Comment: Well the n-th number of the sequence is of course the sum of odd numbers from 1 to 2n - 1:)

Comment: This is not a homework-writing service. You need to find the logic in this list and then duplicate it with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this... ;)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
   int result = i * i;
   System.out.printLn(result);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I won't give out the answer but I'll give you a hint.
That is a list of the first 10 perfect squares. So you just need one loop to go through 10 values and get their square.

Comment: @decPL this answers "where do I go from here" just fine.

Answer (score 0):

for loop to generate `“1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100”`

```
class series
{
     public static void main(String[]args)
     {
        int i,j;
        for(i=1; i<=10; i++) {
             j=i*i;
             System.out.println(j);
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate the numbers, and then append the list:

```
for (int i =1; i <= 10; i++) {    
    System.out.print(i*i + " ");
}
```

Comment: That is very similar to the answer by NeoP5,

Answer (score -1):

```
class forloops
{
    public static void main ()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i = i + 1)
        {
            System.out.println (i * i + "ans");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding any explanation.

Comment: This a) doesn't provide a correct main method b) doesn't output in the format the OP wanted c) doesn't provide the same list of numbers and d) ignores Java idioms such as naming and incrementing. Please consider editing your answer to correct these points.